# Dispose() в структуре

Tags: c#

```
public struct S : IDisposable
{
    private bool dispose;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        dispose = true;
    }
    public bool GetDispose()
    {
        return dispose;
    }
}
```

В примере ниже будет выведено: `false false`

```
var s = new S();
using (s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
}
Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
```

Почему второй раз вышло `false`, ведь метод `Dispose()` вызвался?
Спасибо.

Comment: а почему вы решили что он вызвался?

Comment: Он вызывался (добавьте Console.WriteLine в Dispose  - текст будет выведен).

Comment: @qpeela я запустил в отладке, метод вызвался, полю `dispose ` присвоилось true

Comment: Структуры могут произвольным образом копироваться, так что `IDisposable` для структуры — плохая идея. А почему нельзя использовать класс?

Comment: @VladD увидел на [одном сайте](https://metanit.com/sharp/interview/1.1.php) этот вопрос, стало интересно

Answer (score 13, accepted):

На эту тему есть хорошая [статья](https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box/) от Липперта.

Конкретно на Ваш вопрос ответ будет таков: код

```
using (s)
{
...
}
```

на самом деле будет выполнен как

```
using (S s2=s)
{
...
}
```

А поскольку структуры копируются по значению, а не по ссылке, все действия будут производиться над копией, а не над исходным экземпляром. И `Dispose` будет применён к копии.

Comment: А если создавать прям в using - поможет?

Comment: так обратиться можно будет только внутри `using`. Так что не поможет - просто обратиться не сможете