# Неочевидное поведение блока using в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Наткнулся на такой необычный код на METANIT. Объявлена структура:

```
public struct S : IDisposable
{
    private bool dispose;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        dispose = true;
    }
    public bool GetDispose()
    {
        return dispose;
    }
}
```

И есть такой код, который использует ее:

```
var s = new S();
using (s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
}
Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
```

Код выводит `false, false`, хотя казалось, что должно выводиться `false, true`. Самое интересное то, что если структуру `S` сделать классом, то будет выводиться ожидаемое значение :)

Объясните, что происходит за кулисами с переменной `s`? Почему для структуры будет `false, false`, а для класса - `false, true`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1330571/5045688

Comment: Интересно, есть ли вообще в природе люди, что имплементят IDisposable на структурах в проде, это же дичь :)

Comment: Похоже, что это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637091/212981)

Comment: @tym32167 - вспомнил одно [обсуждение](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/4830779.all), где disposable структура смотрится неплохо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ваш код с `using` разворачивается следующим образом:

```
var s = new S();
var using_s = s;
try {
    Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
} finally {
    using_s.Dispose();
}
Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
```

`using` вызыват `Dispose` не на вашей переменной `s` а на своей собственной переменной. И соответственно поле `dispose` обновляется не у переменной `s`.

Для примера можно рассмотреть [следующий код](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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):

```
using System;
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var s = new S();
        using (s)
        {
            s.Mark = 42;
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetDispose());
        var c1 = new C();
        using (c1)
        {
            c1.Mark = 42;
            Console.WriteLine(c1.GetDispose());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(c1.GetDispose());
        var c2 = new C();
        using (c2)
        {
            c2 = new C { Mark = 42 };
            Console.WriteLine(c2.GetDispose());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(c2.GetDispose());
    }
}
public struct S : IDisposable
{
    public int Mark;
    private bool dispose;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Mark);
        dispose = true;
    }
    public bool GetDispose()
    {
        return dispose;
    }
}
public class C : IDisposable
{
    public int Mark;
    private bool dispose;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Mark);
        dispose = true;
    }
    public bool GetDispose()
    {
        return dispose;
    }
}
```

В случаях `s.Mark = 42;` и `c2 = new C { Mark = 42 };` назначение переменной внутри блока `using` не влияет на значение поля `Mark`, выводимое методом `Dispose`, так как `using` вызывает `Dispose` на своей собственной переменной. И компилятор даже выводит соответствующие предупреждение.

В случае с `c1.Mark = 42;` происходит не изменение переменной, а изменение объекта, на который она указывает.

Comment: Копия переменной по значению, вот оно что. )